# How to consistently search and replace RTF text

Tags: outlook, vsto, rtf

Thanks for looking.

## Background

I am working on a MS Outlook plug in that requires certain text to be injected into the body of a new meeting request when a button click event fires.

The meeting request window only allows plain text or RTF (no HTML). The text that my application needs to enter should be able to be swapped out when the button is clicked again, but should not remove any text that the user may have added either above or below mine.

For now, I use a string of underscores with a leading and trailing set of hidden slashes like this:

`\v//\v0__________________________________________________________________`

`{MY CUSTOM TEXT GOES IN BETWEEN}`

`__________________________________________________________________\v//\v0`

## Problem

With plain text, this is not a problem, but the problem arises when the user edits the body, and then clicks the update button again, it seems that the structure of the RTF encoding changes in a way that is not predictable and I therefore can not search for my text boundaries. For example, after the user adds their own text and clicks the "update button", my code now receives the following which I am unable to find using `IndexOf()`:

`//}{\\rtlch _______________________________________________________________`

## Question

Is their an easier, more consistent way to have essentially merge fields in RTF that the user may edit? I essentially just need to swap in or out a chunk of very simple text regardless of whether the user has written above or below it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually HTML for appointments is supported by Outlook 2016. In any case however, Inspector.WordEditor returns an instance of the Word's Document object, so you can add a bookmark around your text using the Word Object Model rather then by injecting text visible to the end user.